# Why can printing the content of the object returned by itertools.takewhile() break code that uses it later?

Tags: python

if `print(list(ns))` is added, the result is `50`, while if `print(list(ns))` is deleted, the result is `0`, why?

```
import itertools

def PI(N):
    natuals = itertools.count(1,2) #start=1,step=2
    ns = itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x <= 2*N-1, natuals)
    #print(list(ns))
    na = map(lambda x: x/2, ns)#(-1)**(y//2)*4/y
    return sum(na)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(PI(10))
```

Comment: Because [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) makes an iterator.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory/48393588#48393588 (the 1st part - that covers this particular aspect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `itertools.takewhile` return an iterator, and when you apply `list` on `ns`, you iterate over the iterator and receive to end, then get nothing for the next statement (`na`), when you call the iterator again (`ns`).

Hence, it does not happen when you just print the `ns` instead of `list(ns)`.